# Web application stops after console warning

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

I am facing problem in my web application. Whenever  **592 console messages are not shown.** in my console window, It stops my application. it does not move to next.

At the starting one more warning is there
**Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check http://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.**

would you please suggest why this warning happened[image] and solution for this.

Comment: Well it shows that it cannot find the jQuery library file, so if any of your code relies on jQuery your code is not going to work

Answer (score 0):

Let's go point by point,

> Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of
>   its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.

This warning comes when you try to make synchronous AJAX call. You might have use either simple XMLHttpRequest object or jQuery to make AJAX call. Why synchronous AJAX calls are deprecated? Read 'async' attribute explanation of 'open' method [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

Simple XMLHttpRequest object

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax_info.txt",**true**); // Definition: open(method,url,async)
xmlhttp.send();
```

Using jQuery,

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/Page/Method",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify({ ParameterName: paramValue }),
        async: **true**
    })
```

Coming back to the error message - 'Failed to load resource', it is loud and clear that jQuery lib file is not found on the server. Fix the path or make sure  that resource is available on the server at requested location.